# Merge with multiple columns and refill NAN values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, replace, merge

I have df1 that looks like this:

```
STATE      YEAR       EVENT_TYPE       DAMAGE
   ALABAMA    1962       Tornado          27
   ALABAMA    1962       Flood            7
   ALABAMA    1963       Thunderstorm     12
...
```

and df2 that looks like this:

```
STATE      YEAR       TORNADO      THUNDERSTORM      FLOOD
   ALABAMA     1962       NaN          NaN           NaN
   ALABAMA     1963       NaN          NaN           NaN
...
```

And I want to merge these two dataframes together, so the final output looks like this:

```
STATE      YEAR       TORNADO      THUNDERSTORM      FLOOD   
  ALABAMA    1962       27           NaN              7
...
```

Having hard time figuring out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`merge` the pivoted `df1`:

```
cols = ['STATE', 'YEAR']

out = df2[cols].merge(df1.pivot(index=cols, columns='EVENT_TYPE', values='DAMAGE'),
                      left_on=cols, right_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Concat two dataframes.

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
```

Concat two dataframes and replace nan with 0, or whatever value you desire.

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0).df.fillna(0)
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted to keep NaN values, when no choice was available.

Comment: I may have misunderstood but the title says "refill NAN values in Python", but then his desired output has NaN values. Needs clarification

Comment: But the example output provided by the OP contains NaN values. I see your point though, maybe clarification is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df1.update(df2)` to avoid `NaN` positions (if possible):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np

NaN = np.nan

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2  ],[3,NaN],[NaN,NaN]], columns = ('X','Y'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,NaN],[3,4  ],[NaN,6  ]], columns = ('X','Y'))

df1.update(df2)

print(df1)
# output
#    X    Y
# 0  1.0  2.0
# 1  3.0  4.0
# 2  NaN  6.0
```